# How to save TimeStamp in single column using hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager

How do I save timestamps in mysql DB using a hibernate entity in specific format.

Hibernate Entity Class:

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name="created_on", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private LocalDateTime createdOn;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name="updated_on", nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime updatedOn; // = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

I have also used DateTimeFormatter and SimpleDateFormat but they all gave the same error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unsupported property type [java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter] for @CreationTimestamp or @UpdateTimestamp generator annotation
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Which (exact) version of Hibernate do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that one of the non-static fields is of type `DateTimeFormatter` and is annotated with `@CreationTimestamp` or `@UpdateTimestamp` which is illegal. These annotation can only be applied to fields of type `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, `java.time.LocalDateTime` etc.